# Perl in place editing within a script (rather than one liner)

Tags: perl

So, I'm used to the `perl -i` to use perl as I would `sed` and in place edit.

The docs for `$^I` in `perlvar`:

> $^I
>   The current value of the inplace-edit extension. Use undef to disable inplace editing.

OK. So this implies that I can perhaps mess around with 'in place' editing in a script?

The thing I'm having trouble with is this:

If I run:

```
perl -pi -e 's/^/fish/' test_file
```

And then deparse it:

```
BEGIN { $^I = ""; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    s/^/fish/;
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
```

Now - if I were to want to use `$^I` within a script, say to:

```
 foreach my $file  ( glob "*.csv" ) {
     #inplace edit these files - maybe using Text::CSV to manipulate? 
 }
```

How do I 'enable' this to happen? Is it a question of changing `$_` (as `s/something/somethingelse/` does by default) and letting perl implicitly print it? Or is there something else going on?

My major question is - can I do an 'in place edit' that applies a CSV transform (or XML tweak, or similar).

I appreciate I can open separate file handles, read/print etc. I was wondering if there was another way. (even if it is only situationally useful).

Comment: You can do in place edit for record based files like CSV, but not for XML.

Comment: I was thinking with `XML` using something like `XML::Twig`s handlers, `purge` and `flush`.

Comment: Having said that - `XML::Twig` has `parsefile_inplace` so this is moot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The edit-in-place behaviour that is enabled by the `-i` command-line option or by setting `$^I` works only on the `ARGV` file handle. That means the files must either be named on the command line or `@ARGV` must be set up within the program

This program will change all lower-case letters to upper-case in all CSV files. Note that I have set `$^I` to a non-null string, which is advisable while you are testing so that your original data files are retained

```
use strict;
use warnings;

our $^I = '.bak';

while ( my $file = glob '*.csv' ) {

  print "Processing $file\n";

  our @ARGV = ($file);

  while ( <ARGV> ) {
     tr/a-z/A-Z/;
     print;
  }
}
```

Comment: So just to clarify - is it the `print;` that's the important element, or does it have to modify and output `$_`?

Comment: tested - printing anything replaces the content in the file. Seems to only do so within 'while' loop.

Comment: @Sobrique: No, it's the `<>` operator that does the magic (I don't think `ARGV->readline` works the same way) when it opens the files in `@ARGV` to read them. It renames the original file and opens a new file for output on `ARGVOUT` with the original name, and does a `select ARGVOUT` so you don't have to specify a handle in the `print` statements

Answer (score 2):

There is a *much* simpler answer, if your script is *always* going to do in-place editing and your OS uses shebang:

```
#!perl -i
while (<>) {
    print "LINE: $_"
}
```

Will add 'LINE: ' at the beginning of a line for each file it's given. (Note that you'd probably use the full path to perl, i.e., "#!/usr/bin/perl -i")

You can also call your script as:

```
% perl -i <script> <file1> <file2> ...
```

To run script as an in-place editor on file1, file2, etc.., if you don't have shebang support.