# Search and Replace not saving to file

Tags: perl, search, replace

I am new to Perl been working about a day with it. I am trying to write a script that will go to every .cpp file and .hpp file change the files permission to read and write, while also searching for a string and replacing it. This is what I have so far. I am able to change every files permission to read and write the problem is when I try to replace the string. it prints out correctly but will not save into file. Welcome to any suggestions.

```
#gets first first value of array being past as argument. 
my $path = shift;

#open directory
opendir(DIR, $path) or die "Unable to open $path: $!";
#read in the files
#ignores hidden files eg. .\..\
my @files = grep{!/^\.{1,2}$/} readdir(DIR);
#close directory
close(DIR);
#put full path of file
@files = map {$path . '\\' . $_ } @files;

for (@files){
    #if directory then use recusrion to open file 
    if(-d $_){
        change_permission($_);
    }elsif((-f $_) && (($_ =~m/\.cpp/) || ($_ =~m/\.hpp/) || ($_ =~m/\.txt/))){
        chmod 0666, $_ or die "Couldn't chmod";

        open(DATA, "+<", $_) or die "file could not open $! \n";
            while(<DATA>){
                s/best/worst/ig;
                print;
            }

        close(DATA) or die "Couldn't close file properly $! \n" ;


    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Perl tag. If in addition to an answer for your question, you would like to get some constructive feedback on your code, please feel free to post it to [codereview.se] in the _perl_ tag and the _beginner_ there. I see some things that can be improved here.

Comment: Related, could be a duplicate, but would require significant changes to the program: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31024980/1331451

Comment: In short, your [`print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) prints to `STDOUT`; it is like `print STDOUT $_;`.  It can't, and shouldn't, magically change the file. You should write out the new content to another file and then move it over the original. See about this [in perlfaq5](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change,-delete,-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file,-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file?) for example, and search for SO posts.

Comment: I'd suggest _to not_ use `'+<'` mode.  Either read `'<'` or write `'>'` or append `'>>'`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Path::Tiny;

my $p = shift // '.';
my $iter = path($p)->iterator({recurse => 1});
while( my $path = $iter->() ) {
        $path->chmod("ug+w");
        $path->edit( sub { s/best/worst/ } ) if( -f $path && $path =~ /\.([ch]pp|txt)$/i );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `print;` you are printing to `STDOUT` because that's the selected file handle. Your output is then visible on the screen, but does not get changed in the file. The fact that you opened it for reading and writing does not matter here.

You can print to a file handle by using the `print HANDLE ARGS` form.

```
print DATA $_;
```

(Note that `DATA` is a really bad idea for your handle, as that is a default-handle provided by Perl to read the `__DATA__` section of your script. And in general, you should be using lexical file handles and three-argument `open`, so it would become `open my $fh, '+<', $filename or die $!`.)

However, implementing the read/write is not done by simply writing to correct handle. This will mess up Perl's idea of where you currently are in the file.

It makes more sense to use [the approach outlined in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31024980/1331451), and take advantage of Perl's built-in in-place editing like the `-i` command line switch does.

> ```
>   our @ARGV = ($file);
>
>   while ( <ARGV> ) {
>      tr/a-z/A-Z/;
>      print;
>   }
> ```

To apply it to your code, you'll have to do this. I have on purpose not fixed all the style and security issues with your code. See my comment about codereview for that.

```
# elsif (...) {
    chmod 0666, $_ or die "Couldn't chmod";

    @ARGV = ($_);
    while(<DATA>){
        s/best/worst/ig;
        print;
    }
}
```