# How to pass a variable line number in sed substitute command

Tags: regex, linux, perl, unix, sed

I am  trying to do a `sed` operation like this

```
sed -i '100s/abc/xyz/' filename.txt
```

I wanted 100 in a variable say $var from a perl script. So, I am trying like this

```
system("sed -i "${vars}s/abc/xyz/" filename.txt").
```

This is throwing some error.

Again when I am doing like this putting system command in single quotes:

```
system('sed -i "${vars}s/abc/xyz/" filename.txt')
```

this is substituting wrongly. What can be done?

Comment: Try this: `system("sed -i $vars's/abc/xyz/' filename.txt").`

Comment: @anubhava I guess you meant `system("sed -i '${vars}s/abc/xyz/' filename.txt")`. Better and safer would be to use `system(qw{sed -i}, "${vars}s/abc/xyz/",  qw{filename.txt})`.

Comment: A suggestion.  It is altogether about a dozen lines of code to do this nicely in straight Perl, but I would recommend that you do that. This "one line" entails far more complexity with possible failures and murky error reporting, may depend on systems/version, is less efficient  ... it's just not worth it, I think

Answer (score 1):

Better and safer is to use the LIST variant of `system`, because it avoids unsafe shell command line parsing. The command, `sed` in your case, will receive the command line arguments un-alterated and without the need to quote them.

NOTE: I added `-MO=Deparse` just to illustrate what the one-liner compiles to.

NOTE: I added `-e` to be on the safe side as you have `-i` on the command line which expects a parameter.

```perl
 $ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'system(qw{sed -i -e}, "${vars}s/abc/xyz/", qw{filename.txt})'
 system(('sed', '-i', '-e'), "${vars}s/abc/xyz/", 'filename.txt');
 -e syntax OK
```

---

Of course in reality it would be easier just to do the processing in Perl itself instead of calling `sed`...

Comment: Putting `sed -i -e` as a single argument looks weird, shouldn't you be using `system(qw(sed), qw(-i), qw(-e), ...)` if only for legibility?

Comment: Well, IMHO then better would be `system('sed', '-i', '-e', ...)`. But quoting is the whole point of the `qw()` operator, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah but the resulting extra parentheses in `system(('sed', '-i', '-e'), ...)` are what I'm getting at. I have no problem with using `qw(sed -i -e)` if you merge that with the following arguments into a single list.

Comment: @tripleee the extra parentheses are an artifact of [B::Deparse](https://metacpan.org/pod/B::Deparse). So in reality you get those all the time when you use `qw()` but as you don't see them, you don't bother :-)

Answer (score 0):

Shelling out to `sed` from within `perl` is a road to unnecessary pain. You're introducing additional quoting and variable expansion layers, and that's at best making your code less clear, and at worst introducing bugs accidentally.

Why not just do it in native `perl` which is considerably more effective. Perl even allows you to do in place editing if you want.

But it's as simple as:

```
open ( my $input, '<', 'filename.txt'); 
open ( my $output, '>', 'filename.txt.new'); 

select $output; 
while ( <$input> ) {
   if ( $. == $vars ) { 
       s/abc/xyz/
   }
   print;
 }
```

Or if you're really keen on the in place edit, you can look into setting `$^I:

[Perl in place editing within a script (rather than one liner)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31024980/perl-in-place-editing-within-a-script-rather-than-one-liner)

But I'd suggest 'just' renaming the file after you're done is as easy.