# My perl replace dash pattern wipes out all file contents

Tags: perl

In my code below I am trying to replace the pattern of "---- ------" with the corresponding number of spaces. When I run the code, all the file contents are wiped out. I cannot figure out why. I have the sample text below where the replacements are to be done.
I would appreciate assistance.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Path;
use File::Copy;
use feature 'unicode_strings';
use utf8;    

my $IN;
my $dir;

opendir $dir, $Dirs[$mm] or die "opendir failed on $Dirs[$mm]: $! ($^E)";

while (my $file = readdir $dir) {        #reading input directory
    next if -d $file;

    if ($file =~ /Ranked/) {
        print "$file\n";
        open ($IN, "+> $Dirs[$mm]/$file") or die "open '$file': failed $! ($^E)";

        while (<$IN>) {
            s/---- ------/           /g;
            print "$_\n";
        }

        close $dir;
        exit;
    }
}

END
```

```
                          Ranked Rainfall: Jun
                          ********************
CHIPAT01     CHIPEP01     CHOMA001     ISOKA001     KABOMP01     KABWE001     KABWE002     KAFIRO01     KAFUE001     KALABO01     KAOMA001     KASAMA01     KASEMP01

Year Rnfl Year Rnfl Year Rnfl Year Rnfl Year Rnfl Year Rnfl Year Rnfl Year Rnfl Year Rnfl Year Rnfl Year Rnfl Year Rnfl Year Rnfl 1968 17.0 2003 13.2 2000 29.2 2004 3.1 1988 13.3 1988 2.8 ---- ------ 1967 2.8 1966 1.3 2009 2.3 1965 10.7 1968 11.9 1988 6.0 1983 5.8 2011 6.1 1966 14.0 2002 2.0 1965 9.4 1960 0.5 ---- ------ ---- ------ 1960 0.6 ---- ------ 2009 1.8 1952 0.8 1940 5.1 1974 4.6 1996 0.6 1997 4.5 ---- ------ 1966 2.3 1986 0.1 ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ 1966 0.3 1936 0.3 1966 4.8 1960 3.3 2007 0.5 1988 4.0 ---- ------ Ave 0.5 Ave 0.1 ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ Ave 0.2 1965 1.8 1999 0.3 2002 3.7 ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ 1948 1.6 Ave 0.1 2003 3.6 ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ 1971 1.0 ---- ------ 1955 3.3 ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ 1978 0.9 ---- ------ 1976 2.5 ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ 1961 0.5 ---- ------ 1975 1.6 ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ 1946 0.5 ---- ------ 1978 1.6 ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ 1967 0.5 ---- ------ 2011 1.4 ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ Ave 0.4 ---- ------ 1960 1.3 ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ 1964 0.3 ---- ------ 2009 1.0 ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ 1996 0.6 ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ 1969 0.6 ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ Ave 0.5 ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ 1958 0.5 ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ 1979 0.3 ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------
```

Comment: Please read documentation for [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open) and particularly on modes. Perhaps you intended `open(my $in, '<', $fname) or die "Error message"`. Following [webpage] has open modes table with a description of the mode. File open with a mode `"+> $fname"` truncates file and then allow to write into it -- you truncate your files and only then try to write into it.

Comment: Link to [webpage](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_files.htm).

Comment: Desired operation can be achieved on a file with a command like following `perl -pi.bak -e 's/-/ /g' some_file.dat`

Comment: Code is not runnable in the current condition: `Global symbol "@Dirs" requires explicit package name`, and same for `$mm`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading and writing to the same file at the same time requires some care. Here, you are using `+>` to read and write to `$file` at the same time. However, the documentation of [`open`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open#About-modes) warns that:

> You can put a `+` in front of the `>` or `<` to indicate that you want both read and write access to the file; thus `+<` is almost always preferred for read/write updates--the `+>` mode would clobber the file first

Instead, you should write to a temporary file. Once you're done writing, you can replace the original file with the temporary one. To open a temporary file, you can use the [`File::Temp`](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Temp) module. To replace the original file with the new one, you can use `move` from the [`File::Copy`](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Copy) module. Your code corrected:

```
use File::Temp qw(tempfile);
use File::Copy;

while (my $file=readdir $dir) {
    next if -d "$dir/$file";
    if($file =~ /Ranked/){
        print "$file\n";

        my ($out_fh, $out_filename) = tempfile();
        open (my $IN, "<", "$Dirs[$mm]/$file") or die "open '$file': failed $! ($^E)";
        while( <$IN> ){
            s/---- ------/           /g;
            print $out_fh $_;
        }
        close $out_fh;
        copy($out_filename, "$Dirs[$mm]/$file");
    }
}
```

Note that it's important to close `$out_fh` before `copy`ing it.

---

Small tips:

- `next if -d $file` should be `next if -d "$dir/$file"`.
- You should declare your variables in the narrowest scope possible. This means that instead of starting your script with `my $IN;` and later do `open $IN, ...`, you should do `open my $IN, ...`. Same thing for `my $dir` and `opendir`.

---

Alternative solutions:

- Perl has a built-in mechanism for in-place file editing, but it's more suitable for one-liners than for full scripts. This is enabled by the [`-i` command-line switch](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-i%5Bextension%5D), but it can also be used [outside of one-liners](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31025531/4990392) if needed.
- Some CPAN packages (such as [`File::Inplace`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Inplace) can be used to avoid having to write the whole `tempfile`/`move` boilerplate yourself.

Comment: This works perfect @Dada. Thank you very much. Just one remaining issue. The blank lines that remain after, I want to get rid of them. I have s/^\s+$//g in my code, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: That code (s/^\s+$//g) actually works. Thanks again.

Comment: @ZiloreMumba Perfect. Happy to help :)