# How to replace a String in a file with another string which contains single quotes using perl script

Tags: perl, sed

I have a text file in UNIX (say config.cfg) which has data like below.
Key and value seperated by tab.

```
monitorinput    'false'
inputDir  ''
useSsl  'false'
enableSorting     'false'
inputtimeunit    'Day'
```

I want to update the value of inputDir using perl or shell script.

before update:

```
inputDir  ''
```

so after update it should be

```
inputDir  '/home/user/pricing/inflow/'
```

I tried many things. not able to put value within the quotes.

```
use File::Basename;
use File::Path;
use File::Copy;
use File::Find;
use File::Path qw(make_path remove_tree);
use Getopt::Std;

my $target_conf_file="/home/pricing/config.cfg";
my $node_backup_dir = "/home/user/pricing/inflow/";



#my $commndresult= system("sed -i 's|^inputDir.*|inputDir\t'${node_backup_dir}'|g' $target_conf_file");
my $commndresult= system("sed -i 's|^inputDir.*|inputDir    '$node_backup_dir'|g' $target_conf_file");
if ( $commndresult == 0 )
{
        print "\nInput Directory updated";

}
```

Comment: `sed -i "/^inputDir[[:space:]]/ s#''#'home/user/pricing/inflow/'#" config.cfg`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really no need to drag `sed` into this when you can just use `perl` directly. The handy [`Path::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) module makes it trivial:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Path::Tiny;

my $target_conf_file="/home/pricing/config.cfg";
my $node_backup_dir = "/home/user/pricing/inflow/";

path($target_conf_file)->edit_lines(sub {
    $_ = "inputDir\t'${node_backup_dir}'" if /^inputDir\s/
});
```

or if you can't install an extra module for some reason, (ab)using the behavior of `-i` (Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31025531/9952196)):

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $target_conf_file="/home/pricing/config.cfg";
my $node_backup_dir = "/home/user/pricing/inflow/";

our $^I = "";
our @ARGV = ($target_conf_file);
while (<ARGV>) {
    $_ = "inputDir\t'${node_backup_dir}'" if /^inputDir\s/;
    print;
}
```

Comment: Since i have limitation to use path::Tiny i took the second option. it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a typical example of using `awk`

```
% <config.cfg awk -v q=\' '$1 == "inputDir" { $2 = q "/home/user/pricing/inflow/" q } { print; }'
monitorinput   'false'
inputDir '/home/user/pricing/inflow/'
useSsl 'false'
enableSorting  'false'
inputtimeunit  'Day'
```